# The application I wrote is listed as malware. How to fix it?

Tags: applications, installer, distribution

I have a program that I wrote in [Delphi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarcadero_Delphi). The program is available for download, but some antivirus like Norton detects it as malware, while other antivirus, like [AVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVG_%28software%29), has no issues with it.

Moreover, Google Chrome also gives a malware warning when you want to download the program from my website.

Is there some way to prevent this, apart from putting the EXE file in a [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) file?

Comment: Putting it into a zip file is not a solution. Rather find out what's causing this, and fix it. Or, if that turns out impossible, at least explain it to users up front.

Comment: That is the thing, I have no idea how to even begin to find out what if causing this. My programs installer is built with Zipinstaller.

Comment: what version of Delphi and what type off app is it? There were issues like this with console apps compiled by a specific Delphi version. Searching Stack Overflow and/or google for Delphi and virus software should bring up relevant information.

Comment: It was developed using Delphi XE2 and it is a point of sale program for hair salons.

Comment: norton is overzealous about what it thinks is a virus (some version classed itself as a virus)

Comment: I just scanned my installer at http://virusscan.jotti.org and I get the following malware alerts: PSWTool.W32.MailPassView.130 and a  Backdoor.XiaoBird.8 (paranoid heuristics) alert. I have no idea how to fix something like this. This program is like my first program I wrote.

Comment: As I said: search stack overflow (http://stackoverflow.com) and/or google. You are not the only one suffering from this and there are solutions/workarounds out there. The Embarcadero forums (http://edn.embarcadero.com) should also help. Btw, when you answer someone's comment, it helps to start with their name preceded by an '@' character as they will then receive a notification that you responded.

Comment: What AVG does or doesn't call a virus isn't really a meaningful data point.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: [Insert snarky comment about "some version" being correct here]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should try to contact Norton's (Symantec's?) customer service. I believe this is standard practice among vendors of legit programs which are wrongly flagged as viruses.

Answer (score 11):

Something to keep in mind:  It might really be infected.  There is a virus out there that infects Delphi itself.  If you're infected with it any executable that Delphi produces will be infected.

Comment: The things is the installer was tested with other anti-virus and nothing was detected. It is Norton that is giving issues, and the problem is that a lot of people are using Norton

Answer (score 8):

In case anyone is interested, this article treats a similar case with a program that's just a do-nothing WinMain function - [The Case of Evil WinMain](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71128/The-Case-of-Evil-WinMain).

> Story about how a third of all antivirus programs has gone crazy for no obvious reason...
>
> ```
> #include <windows.h>
>
> int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE inst,HINSTANCE prev,LPSTR cmd,int show) {
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> #### So what caused additional antivirus software vendors to go NUTS?
>
> I am starting to feel that they simply started to search for malware in [libc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations) itself. If so then that's kind of strange because there is not that many versions of libc linked to nearly everything under the sun over and over.
>
> **[Here](http://sites.google.com/site/minimalistscorner/EmptyWinmainFalsePos.zip?attredirects=0&d=1)** is the mentioned VS 2008 ProjectFile + source + resulting binary not doing anything along with **[vtotal results](http://www.virustotal.com/analisis/fad21b2be19f5619bbe538736ea720ff91ecc1f991087caa9d2cecb34d29c8ce-1270576549)** for it.
>
> But please go ahead and create an **EMPTY C++ project** to see it yourself.
> Add a cpp file with this **empty winmain** doing nothing build **release** ...